# Setting a text right to a pic which both link to a same page in the middle of the pic

Tags: html, css

In the mobile theme of my site there shall be a picture with text right to it which both link to the parent menu. However, I can't adjust the text height (it should be in the center of the picture height but the text appears at the bottom of the picture, see the pictures:

[image]

(left current, right as it should be)

My current files:

in html:

```
<div id="topbar">
//<div id="title">Über</div>
//<div id="bluerightbutton"><a href="/m/language.html">More</a></div>
<div id="leftnav"><a href="/m/de/futuristic-os">futuristicOS</a></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#leftnav a:before{content:url("../images/leftback.png");}
#leftnav a:first-child{z-index:2; padding-bottom: 50%; width:auto}
#leftnav a{z-index:3;margin-left:-4px;border-width:0 5px 0 13px;padding-right:4px;float:left}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, I would set the `line-height` of your text to the value of the height as your image. This should vertically center it on the image.

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/CLd4t/1/

Comment: exactly as this, but the image link shall be in the css file and not in the html file

Comment: Here's an adjusted fiddle with the image as a background-image of the a tag.
http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/CLd4t/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#leftnav a {
    display: table-cell;  // Allows vertical-align & height
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* Now you can adjust height too, so do that until you're satisfied */
}
```

Comment: This adjusts the line height, but the image disappears... And when I add the picture (#leftnav a:before{content:url("../images/leftback.png");}) then the text goes down again..